# Adding Task<T> operation contract to WCF service contract

Tags: wcf, async-await, operationcontract

I am working on a file with all synchronous WCF operation contracts.
I am adding a new method, or new contract which will use async-await pattern.

My method will have a similar signature to this

```
Task<TResult> DispatchOperation(...)
```

`svcutil` is not generating this correctly with `Task<TResult>` return type so I am not able to use await nor can I use that async pattern.

I know svcutil generation command has the `/async` flag which ends up generating methods with Synchronous and Aysnc pattern (Using Begin / End style), but for that particular new method I am adding, it should be only async via Task, Async Await pattern. is this not possible?

Comment: The ```svcutil``` tool in WCF does not natively support generating methods([Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/synchronous-and-asynchronous-operations#task-based-asynchronous-pattern)) with ```Task<TResult>``` return type for async-await. The ```/async``` in ```svcutil``` generates methods with ```IAsyncResult``` return type and ```Begin/End```, which is not the same as the ```Task<TResult>``` async-await pattern.

Comment: Thanks @KeyboardCorporation 
so what would be the solution to that? I assume not using svcutil at all?

Comment: You can manually modify the generated code to use the ```Task``` pattern. Do this by changing the method signature to return a ```Task<TResult>``` and then use the ```async``` keyword. This approach requires manual intervention and the changes would be overwritten if you regenerate the proxy using ```svcutil```.

Comment: Have you tried [dotnet svcutil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-svcutil/)?

Comment: Are you planning to use the resulting contract file on the server side, client side, or both? And are you using original WCF or CoreWCF?

Comment: Since the code base is shared and I am not the only one using it, I don't have much choice. 
So the auto-generated code will be used by server and client side. Editing manual is not an option since it will be overwritten with every build. I assume only option is new contract. It's WCF original.

Comment: This document describes a way not to use Svcutil: [Custom WSDL Publication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-wsdl-publication)